# Unable to pull from bitbucket or github repository using sourcetree

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I've suddenly started having problems pulling from and pushing to any remote repositories using SourceTree on my laptop. 4 hours ago I had no problem accessing my repository and pulled the latest code into my local repository. I then went to work and tried to push to the same repository with the same credentials to BitBucket and received this error:

> FATAL ERROR: Network error: Software caused connection abort
>
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

I then tried from git bash and got a similar error. So I regenerated my SSH key and added it to BitBucket. Now I have command line access to the repo. I did the same thing using Putty for my SourceTree key and added that to BitBucket but I still get access denied.

I could use the command line to push and pull but I'd rather use SourceTree. Particularly given that it was working fine this morning. Is there anything else I can try to get this working again? I've restarted SourceTree and rebooted since adding the new key but still no joy

Comment: Did you got any solution for this issue?@levelnis